# The set of isomorphisms, $Iso(X,Y)$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y $ be Banach. I want to show that,

$GL(X,Y) = \{ A\in L(X,Y), B \in L(Y,X) : BA= id_{x} \ \ \text{and}  \ BA = id_{y} \} \subset^{open} L(X,Y)$

My attempt,
Let $T \in Iso(X,Y), \ Q \in L(X,Y)$ 
\begin{equation}
Q= T-(T-Q)\\
=T(id_{x} - T^{-1}(T-Q))\\
=T(id_{x} - \lambda )
\end{equation}

Letting $\lambda = T^{-1}(T-Q) = id_{x} - T^{-1}Q$

Taking the norm of this,

$||\lambda|| =||T^{-1}(T-Q)|| \\
 \le ||T^{-1}||||T-Q|| \\
 < ||T^{-1}||||T^{-1}||^{-1} = 1$

So $id - \lambda$ is invertible (and hence so is Q as it is the product of invertibles).
As Q is continuous,
is this justifiying that $Iso(X,Y) \subset^{open} $ of $L(X,Y)$?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is $L(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Neumann series:

Let $A \in Iso(X, Y)$ and $B \in L(X, Y)$ such that $||A-B||<1/||A^{-1}||$ and write $B = AS$ where $S = (I - (I - A^{-1}B))$. $S$ is invertible if $||I - A^{-1}B|| < 1$ (Neumann series).

Now $||I - A^{-1}B|| \leq ||A^{-1}||\cdot||A-B|| < ||A^{-1}||/||A^{-1}|| = 1$, i.e. $S$ is invertible and B is a composition of invertible operators.

Comment: Could you explain what "B is a composition of invertible operators." implies?

Comment: B is a composition of invertible operators implies that B is invertible too, i.e. it is in Iso(X, Y). Now B is an arbitrary element in an open Ball with center A hence Iso is open in L.