# Openness of the set of all isomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis

In the proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521451/371990, why does the invertibility of operator $B$ imply openness of the set of all isomorphisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $A\in\text{ISO}$, we want to find some $\delta>0$ such that $B_{\delta}(A)\subseteq\text{ISO}$, as what has been shown there, one chooses $\delta=1/\|A^{-1}\|$.

Answer (score 1):

The argument shows that, given an invertible operator $A$, any other operator $B$ "sufficiently close" to $A$ (namely, within a distance $1/\|A^{-1}\|$) is also invertible. In other words, the set of invertible operators contains, together with any element, some ball centered at it. This is what open means in any metric space.

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ is the composition of invertible operators, $B\in\operatorname{Iso}(X,Y)$. So, $B_{\lVert A^{-1}\rVert}(A)\subset\operatorname{Iso}(X,Y)$.

Comment: How's $B$ related to the open ball $B_r(A)$ in your answer?

Comment: The answer that you mentioned shows that, for every $B\in B_{\lVert A^{-1}\rVert}(A)$, $B\in\operatorname{Iso}(X,Y)$.